# Problema en contador if

Tags: java, condiciones, contador

El problema es, contar cuantos digitos 5  tiene un numero, lo eh ejecutado y al momento de imprimir el contador imprime "0" lo eh declarado dentro del "case" y fuera de (hay mas codigo, son dos programas) ya intente sin llaves antes del if, y como aparece el el codigo, le eh cambiado el nombre pero aun asi, no se que mas pueda hacer

```
 case 2:
        int contador=0;
        
        int d=a/10;
        double d1=a%10;
        
        int g=d/10;
        double g1=d1%10;
        
        int h=g/10;
        double h1=g1%10;
        
        int j=h/10;
        double j1=h1%10;
        
        int k=j/10;
        double k1=j1%10;
        
        {
        
        if(d1==5) //si realiza la comparacion
        {
        contador++;//no realiza el contador
        }
        else if (g1==5)//si realiza la comparacion
        {
            contador++;//no realiza el contador
        }
    }
        System.out.println("numero:"+ contador);//me imprime 0
        
    break;
     

}
```

}
}

Comment: Hola. Pon puntos de interrupción y ve revisando el valor de las variables en cada punto. Es el ABC de la depuración de código. En vez de tardar horas rompiéndote el coco, en minutos encontrarás el problema en la mayoría de los casos. Por lo general los puntos de interrupción de activan haciendo click en la parte izquierda, donde están los números de línea. Das un click en la o las líneas donde quiere que se pare y cuando se pare revisas el depurador para ver el valor de los objetos en ese punto.

Comment: y qué número es "a"? si es por ejemplo 500, está bien que te imprima 0 porque tu código solo comprueba los dos últimos números

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque d1 es double y estas comparando contra un entero, prueba comparar asi:
`if(d1==5d)`...

Comment: No recuerdo que los literales de `double` se escriban así. 5.0 querrás decir?